# remove values from a file present in another file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a tab separated file A containing several values per row:

```
A   B   C   D   E
F   G   H   I
J   K   L   M
N   O   P
Q   R   S   T
U   V
X   Y   Z
```

I want to remove from file A the elements contained in the following file B:

```
A   D
J   M
U   V
```

resulting in a file C:

```
B   C   E
F   G   H   I
K   L
N   O   P
Q   R   S   T
X   Y   Z
```

Is there a way of doing this using bash?

Comment: please add what you've tried to question... should the elements from file B be checked on same line of file A or any line?

Comment: Any line. I need all the elements present in file B removed from file A

Comment: Also, all elements in files A and B are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 1):

In case the entries do not contain any special symbols for `sed` (for instance `()[]/\.*?+`) you can use the following command:

```
mapfile -t array < <(<B tr '\t' '\n')
(IFS='|'; sed -r "s/(${array[*]})\t?//g;/^$/d" A > C)
```

This command reads file `B` into an array. From the array a `sed` command is constructed. The `sed` command will filter out all entries and delete blank lines.

In your example, the constructed command ...

```
sed -r 's/(A|D|J|M|U|V)\t?//g;/^$/d' A > C
```

... generates the following file `C` (spaces are actually tabs)

```
B   C   E
F   G   H   I
K   L   
N   O   P
Q   R   S   T
X   Y   Z
```

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ pat = sprintf("%s%s|%s", (pat? pat "|":""), $1, $2); next }
     { 
         gsub("^(" pat ")[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*(" pat ")", "");
         if (NF) print 
     }' file_b file_a
```

The output:

```
B   C   E
F   G   H   I
K   L
N   O   P
Q   R   S   T
X   Y   Z
```